# Get MAC address from IP address

Tags: powershell

I have a script that collects information from remote server one at a time.

```
    $IP = (Get-NetIPAddress -CimSession $i -AddressFamily IPv4 | where { $_.InterfaceAlias -notmatch 'Loopback'}).IPAddress
    $MAC = (Get-NetAdapter -CimSession $i | where {$_.status -eq 'up'}).MacAddress
```

The script works 100% when the machine has 1 NIC.

My issue is when the server has multiple NICs IP & MAC returns `System.Object[]` .
[image]

How do I use the results of "PING" to get the MAC address.

[image: Output sample:]

Output with notepad++, [image: Server with 1 NIC]

[image: Server with 2 NICs]

Comment: Usually the MAC comes from the NIC and each has its own MAC.  So a machine will have more than on MAC.

Comment: What is your expected result / output? If there are multiple nics, or if a nic has multiple addresses you'll get an *array* containing all the values (i.e. ```System.Object[]```) instead of a string containing one value. In the context of your script, you need to decide what *should* happen if there are multiple results...

Comment: The requirement is to provide the primary IP and MAC. when a new server is initially built, there is usually one card that's connected to the network.

This is the card that i want to get information on.

Comment: So what output do you want when there's more than one card attached? Output both? Or somehow determine which one is "primary"? Can you include the code that you're using to output or display the information and show (i) what it's outputting at the moment when there are multiple nics (ii) what you want it to output instead so it can be adapted as appropriate. Your question is an output formatting issue I think, rather than anything to do with network cards / ip addresses specifically here...

Comment: I will update the post with the image of the output cause i'm unable to add it on the comment

Comment: @mclayton, post has been updated. how do i add the complete script for context with the code?

Comment: It looks like you're generating a csv file and opening it in Excel based on your screenshots. Just post the contents of the csv file itself (open in Notepad) as it looks right now, and also **what you want it to look like**. Specifically, you need to explain what your output should look like if your server has 2 nics - should it ignore one (in which case how does the script decide which one to include)? Should it output multiple rows with one row per nic? Or should it combine the information from multiple nics somehow (and how) to populate the IP Address and MAC columns in a single row?

Comment: @mclayton, let me try to elaborate. The thinking i have is as follows: (1) PING the server, save the result. (2) Use the returned IP from PING to get the MAC of the NIC the IP is configured on. (3) The output should ignore/discard any additional NICs. (4) **(in which case how does the script decide which one to include)** - This is what i'm struggling with

Comment: PING Server1 -> 10.200.3.4, Get-NetIPPConfiguration | where {$_.ipv4address -eq 10.200.3.4}. This is what i want to do, but it isn't that simple.

Comment: Is there a place where I can upload the script?

Answer (score 2):

Get-NetIPConfiguration has both.

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | 
  select @{n='ipv4address';e={$_.ipv4address[0]}}, 
         @{n='macaddress'; e={$_.netadapter.macaddress}}

IPv4Address      macaddress
-----------      ----------
182.16.183.105   9C-89-A5-B6-A6-30
173.18.1.1       10-15-5D-4C-E9-C2
```